# IFS assistance or other solution

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I currently have a work in progress spreadsheet that is calculating correctly for one value but not another. What I currently have is a an IF function but I have realised that it needs to have another criteria and also 2 additional values in it to make it work the way I want.

This is the current formula

```
=IF(H77="Long",(L77-N77)*10,IF(H77="Short",(N77-L77)*10,""))
```

As you can see it is referencing column H which I can't change but what I need is both references of 10 need to be different values based on a different column. I have added the image of the structure as well.

What I need is the following and I have tried changing to a IFS function but cant get a valid result. This is not the formula but rather what I am trying to achieve.

`IF C5 = AUDCHF (I have 45 variables) then multiple by 10000 (not 10) then the rest of the formula =IF(H76="Long",(L76-N76)*10,IF(H76="Short",(N76-L76)*10,""))` [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbRJ5.png)

Here is the formula that works but doesn't reference column C

```
=IF(H76="Long",(L76-N76)*10000,IF(H76="Short",(N76-L76)*10000,""))
```

Then on the other changes is if C5 = AUDJPY then multiple by 100. What my spreadsheet is for is simple calculations for different assets that have different currency values.

Happy for formula to be replaced with completely different formula like lookup table etc

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have 45 currencies, much better off using a lookup table.

For example:

```
=IFS(H76="Long",L76-N76,H76="Short",N76-L76)*IF(C5="",10,VLOOKUP(C5,theTable,2,FALSE))
```

where `theTable` is a two column table with the possible matching strings in the first column, and the multiplier in the second column.

*If there is an invalid string in `C5`, the formula will return the `#N/A` error*

[image]